# Why do over-currents destroy IC's?

Tags: current, integrated-circuit, damage

Power driver IC's (like the [L298](http://www2.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/82/cc/3f/39/0a/29/4d/f0/CD00000240.pdf/files/CD00000240.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000240.pdf)) have absolute maximum ratings for peak current, continuous current, and temperature. I get why overtemperature could cause the IC to fail, but, assuming I kept the temperature below that with a big heat sink, why does the maximum continuous current rating apply?

We know the driver can tolerate more than the max continuous current because it can take bursts of up to the max peak current, which is considerably more. So, if I kept the temp low, why couldn't the driver source that max peak current indefinitely?

Note that I gave the L298 as an example. I am asking about IC's in general.

Comment: The heat conductance of any heatsink is much slower than the destruction rate of the IC when the current is high enough.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I meat to ask if there was a reason **other** than temperature, but, if that's the real reason why, post it as an answer.

Comment: Another consideration may be the size/current carrying capability of the bond wires and metalization on the chip (but that leads back to heating...)

Comment: Well, there are other reasons as well, such as a semiconductors Avalanche breakdown. But these are due to overvoltage. But related of course...

Comment: For consideration of a multitude of semiconductor failure modes, consider: http://www.semicon.panasonic.co.jp/en/aboutus/pdf/t04007be-3.pdf that covers many topics, including temperature and current. This could be a good source to refine into a proper answer to this question.

Comment: *"why does the maximum continuous current rating apply?"* One reason could be electron migration, the flow of electrons destroying the internal wiring of the IC. Note that these maximum ratings are manufacturer guaranteed values for (usually) 10 years. You could exceed them and the IC might work for a long time but the manufacturer will not guarantee that the IC will work for 10 years at that higher current.

Answer (score 3):

As current increases, I2R losses increase really fast, you get to a point that the IC will hit its temperature limit even if the heatsink it sitting at 25'C, the internal thermal resistance puts an upper limit on power dissipation. Push the chip hard enough and you could even melt the bond wires (this is what "package limited" means in some mosfet datasheets). At the heart of it, the main limiter is temperature, just like with an electric motor, if you can keep it cool (and you can keep the switches fully enhanced), there's not really that much of a limit. Semiconductors can handle some pretty crazy current densities. (there are physical limitations like not having enough free electrons to carry the current or electromigration where the force of all those electrons literally shreds the metal conductors like an atomic sandblaster, but with power electronics, 99.9% of the time, it'll explode due to instantaneous superheating first).

However, in processors with nanometer scale transistors, electromigration is much more of an issue, the wires are so small that it doesn't take much for the force of the electrons bouncing into metal atoms (definition of resistance) for the metal to start moving in the direction of the current, this can eventually lead to the wire breaking, but that's not an instantaneous process, like corrosion, it takes time. Instantly killing a chip with over current is almost always going to be a thermal issue.

Comment: did you mean "electromigration" instead of "electromitigation"?

Comment: whoops, yeah I think I must need my eyes checked, I'll fix it